# WH_KEYBOARD with Alt+Tab stop working

Tags: c#, c++, windows, hook

When I set up non-global WH_KEYBOARD hook, it works fine and all keys are catched. But if I press Alt+Tab and then return to the window, hook stops its working with no reason.
This is my hook proc where I'm trying to block all keyboard messages for proccess with id = root:

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback (int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{     
 var proc = 0u;
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out proc);
 if (proc != root) return CallNextHookEx(hooks[0], nCode, wParam, lParam);
  return new IntPtr(1);
}
```

For developing I use 32bit Windows in VirtualBox.

**UPDATE:** 
It also doesn't depend on blocking or passing parameters to the next hook: code variant that do nothing then calling next hook stops working after Alt+Tab too. Losing focus and activating of the window doesn't stop hook if it was done not with Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for some samples and analysing my code I've found how to solve this "bug". I should set last two parameters in SetWindowsHookEx function in such way:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD, HookCallback, 
                 IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

but not like this:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD, HookCallback, 
                 GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
```

Comment: Um, you said in your question that you are setting up a non-global hook, but the code you showed in this answer (the "before" version) creates a global hook. That's probably why nobody could help you. You provided incorrect information in the question.